# N-MOSFET Gate to Drain short circuit configuration and Vgs

Tags: mosfet, nmos

I notice that in solution manuals to problems like these, when the gate is shorted to the drain on an NMOS, Vds = Vgs. So Vds >= Vds - Vtn, making the MOSFET always in saturation.

I do not understand why this is, and have not been able to find a diagram that I could make sense of. How can we explain this more visually?

[image]

Here is the problem this schematic came from. Microelectronic circuit design, 5th edition.

[image]

Comment: Is it an examination solution manual written by another struggling student?  Can you give us a link or at least more details?

Comment: Why does the gate to source voltage become equal to gate to drain voltage, when shorted from gate to drain? Like in the schematic I posted. If you want the actual problem from the book I can add it but I thought posting book problems was off limits on here.

Comment: Many thanks for your reference of  the book. I googled and found Chegg's cheat book. https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/microelectronic-circuit-design-5th-edition-solutions-9780073529608?utm_campaign=hwh--long_tail--HK_TBS_DSA&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_content=DSA. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'm sure you ment `Vds >= Vgs - Vth` for a MOSFET in saturation.

`Vds` is defined as the potential difference between drain and source, `Vgs` as the potential difference between gate and source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fblr9k.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By shorting gate and drain, they share the same potential. Therefore, `Vgs = Vds`. That much should be pretty obvios.

Now have a look at the output characteristics of a standard MOSFET below (graphic taken from [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/16415/180075) answer). Focus on one specific value for `Vds`. You can see how the drain current increases with increasing `Vgs` (or rather `Vgs - Vth`). If `Vgs`is smaller than `Vth`, the MOSFET is basically completely blocking. Once `Vgs` is larger than `Vth`, all MOSFETs more or less share the shown behavior. That is why plotting `Vgs - Vth` is more usefull to us than plotting `Vgs` right now.
[image: output characteristics of MOSFET]
The saturation region is the region in the plot, where the drain current is independent of `Vds` and therefore is just a horizontal line. In the linear region, the drain current *is* dependent on `Vds`, and the MOSFET behaves roughly like an ohmic resistor.
Take a closer look at the red line seperating the regions (in reality, this is not a hard transistion but rather a soft change). This line follows the equation `Vds = Vgs - Vth`. Check it yourself!
At the point where it crosses the blue `Vgs - Vth = 4V`, `Vds` is also 4V. The same applies for other values.
If `Vds` is larger, we are on the right of the red line; in the saturation region. If `Vds` is smaller, we are on the left, in the linear region.

To be honest, I'm not sure if there is a deeper physical explanation for this formula or if it is just a convenient coincidence. However, keep in mind that it is not a hard boundary and the whole model of underlying theory of how a MOSFET operates just an approximation.

---

To sum it up, you should

- make sure you understand what the voltages `Vds` and `Vgs` mean in general and for your circuit
- then have a deep look at the output characteristics graph. At least for me, it was the hardest part to wrap my mind around the fact that three quantities are plotted in the same graph. Once you managed that, it becomes an increadibly useful tool while designing and analysing circuits.

Comment: Your answer is excellent, and newbie friendly to me with IQ 97. I really appreciate your suggestion at the end of "taking deep look, ... wrap my mind around the fact that ***three quantities are plotted in the same graph**, ...". I studied a EE diploma ages ago, and I confess that when reading about linear/saturation region of  BJT operation, I had not taken a deep enough look at the graph, and so I did not know, as you said, three quantities are plotted on the same graphs. / to continue, ...

Comment: At that time I only knew a basic graph with X- and Y- axis. I never thought that there can be a graph with three axis, X, Y, and Z!

Comment: to make sure I thoroughly understand your answer, I use the following MOSFET as a case study: IRL540N 100V N-Channel Power MOSFET Datasheet - Infineon: 
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irl540npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153565fc2a62567. I read the data sheet and I have two questions related to the linear/saturation region. The questions are written in the following picture: https://i.imgur.com/zNX2E4W.jpeg. I am designing switching circuits using this IRL540N. I would appreciate it you can answer my questions. Thanks a lot. Cheers.

Comment: For a detailed answer, you should start a new question. In short, measuring Vth with gate and drain shorted is just a useful convention, I guess (correct me if I'm wrong). It makes measuring and comparing of different devices easier. Your points a), b) and c) are all correct.
Consering the graph: it actually only has two axis, but Vgs-Vth can be seen as a parameter which changes the curve.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and very helpful answer. Your guess that shorting gate and drain as a useful convention is very reasonable, and I would have never thought about that. And because I have not seen such a condition in BJT datasheets, I need to google more MOSFET data sheets to convenience/verify myself.  BTW, I am a slow thinker, so it might take me sometime before I let you know my research/verification results. Have a great weekend. Cheers.

Comment: I would like to clarify that my book defines threshold voltages as Vtn and Vtp. Not Vth. Theydo it to not confuse with thevenin voltage so that’s how i write it now. Excellent answer.

Comment: @StrugglingStudent117, I appreciated your clarification very much. Earlier I said I need to use URL540N as case study to "translate" #K. Krull terms to what I know, because I I found his use of terms confusing. I have never read any books on MOS, and I only focus on two parameters: (1) Rds(on), (2) Vgs(th). I don't even care of Vds, because I only play with Logic level trigger N-Ch power MOSFETs. Your question mentions terms like λ, W, L which I never heard of. So I knew I have no prerequisite knowledge to understand your question. / to continue, ...

Comment: However, I was curious to know what you are talking about, so I googled something to read. I guess some other newbies and future readers might also are interested, so I am listing some of the things I might read. The first one is (1) MOS Field-Effect Transistors (MOSFETs) Sedra8e Solved Problems Ch05 (1) (λ W/L etc):
https://learninglink.oup.com/protected/files/content/file/1578581756591-sedra8e_solvedproblems_ch05.pdf.

Comment: And I second reference I might read is the following: (2) Jaeger & Blalock, 4th Ed, Ch 4 Problems ... - UW ECE (The OP's question is 4.34)
https://dunham.ece.uw.edu/ee331/JB4edProb/JaegerBlalock4edCh4ProblemsPP204-216.pdf. Ah lunch time. See you later.

Comment: The third reading is this: (3) (PDF) Microelectronic Circuit Design by Jaeger 4th edition.pdf - Academia.Edu
https://www.academia.edu/35781367/Microelectronic_Circuit_Design_by_Jaeger_4th_edition_pdf

Comment: @StrugglingStudent117, The title of Jaeger's Microelectronic Circuit Design, misled me to think that it was a boring book on MOSFET fabrication, which is what I am least interested, because me EE hobbyist focuses only on application, not at all fabrication. But then when I skimmed the book's preface, I guess the book should be interesting. So I skimmed on the first three chapters, spending about 30 minutes. I found it a good comprehensive introduction book (I give 5 stars or 9/10) for EE newbies, ... My long winded comments stops here. I will begin reading Ch 4. See you later.

Comment: @K.Krull Why does the red line look exponential? Like an e^x function?

Comment: Like it would seem that the red line is it’s own graph WITHIN a graph.. Vds as a function of Vgs - Vth. Sort of ignoring the current on the y axis and instead using Vgs as the Y?. This looks like two graphs with two different Y axis on ONE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115224/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-strugglingstudent117).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Vdd is large enough, it is no different from driving Vgs with a separate voltage high enough to completely turn on the MOSFET so it conducts as much as it can and behaves as a switch (ie. a very low resistance) across the source drain.

Answer (score 0):

In this configuration, the nmos is called an enhancement load, this makes the nmos act like a diode but the curve is follows a square expression instead of exponential, thus making it a non-ohmic resistor, as follows:
[image: A plot showing the current over voltage curve of an enhancement load]
One circuit where this is useful is one in which an enhancement load is placed on top and an nmos is on the bottom, the output is taken from between them, as follows:
[image: A photo of an enhancement load inverter, as described in this post]

When the bottom nmos is turned off, the output will be Vdd - Vth. Turning the bottom nmos on will form a voltage divider, getting the output close to zero. This makes this circuit an inverter, although it is not a particularly good one, it is better than having a resistor as that takes a large amount of space on a chip. A better inverter uses a depletion nmos or CMOS, but that is not relevant here.

The circuit you provided with two depletion loads in series acts just like a voltage divider made out of two equal diodes, so the output voltage is half Vdd. This holds true if each enhancement load has more than its threshold across it, and makes current calculation easier as you only need to consider a single nmos with half the supply voltage.

[image: A photo showing that two equal nmos enhancement loads in series at 5 volts draw the same current as one at 2.5 volts]